# Can smells/gasses pass through a plastic bottle?

Tags: oil

Perhaps this is more suited to chemistry or physics I dunno.

Anyway I have a bottle of engine oil which has been in my boot which has been exposed to strong damp amongst other strong smelling chemicals for a while now.

I’m thinking maybe the bottle is in some way porous and has allowed small chemicals to pass through contaminating the engine oil?  I don’t want to waste the bottle but I don’t want to put harmful things in the engine either.

Or is a bottle of previously open engine oil totally safe despite what may have surrounded it?

Comment: While there are some chemicals that can pass through the polyethylene that most oil bottles are made of today, it seems highly unlikely that you would have these in the boot of your car.  The reason they use poly for bottles is because it's fairly inexpensive and impermeable to nearly everything.  So no, I can't imagine that anything got into such a bottle.

Answer (score 1):

The other stacks would probably be better for a super critical answer, but I can say that I doubt it would be contaminated to a significant degree if the bottle is still holding liquid.

Personally, if I have any doubt at all about my oil I just buy new stuff for my vehicles, but that's just me. That's kind of comes down to an economics question though.